# Template specification for a derived class in an std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

How would I provide a template specialisation for the `Derived` class in this simple case, assuming the `Base` cannot be changed - in my real code, `Base` is a library that I cannot change.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
    public:
        virtual void foo() { std::cout << "In base\n"; }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
        virtual void foo() { std::cout << "In derived\n"; }
};

template<typename T>
void wibble(T &&baz)
{
    std::cout << "In wibble for default\n";
    baz->foo();
}

// How do I provide a specialisation here?
//template<typename what_goes_here>
//void wibble(what_goes_here &&baz)
//{
//    std::cout << "In wibble for derived\n";
//    baz->foo();
//}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> bar = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    
    bar->foo();
    wibble(bar);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to use a separate template when the actual type contained within the shared pointer is `Derived`.

Comment: In the code you have an instance of `shared_ptr<Base>`. The fact that it points towards a `Derived` is technically a run-time information. So you cannot at compile-time disambiguate the two. You can call run-time dynamic casts to figure out what is what but that's it.

Comment: You cannot specialized a template based on the runtime type of `shared_ptr`. If the `wibble` cannot be modified then you cannot do much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper tool here is to use dynamic_cast<Derived*>. This is runtime information and as such must be queried at runtime.

Something like

```
void wibble(std::shared_ptr<Base*> baz){
    if(auto derived =dynamic_cast<Derived*>(baz.get())){
       // user derived pointer.
    }
}
```

should allow you achieve something similar to what you want.
If your keyboard is missing <kbd>*</kbd>, you can also (thanks Eljay)

```
if(auto derived = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(baz)){
    // use derived
}
```

This is just one more case where templates and polymorphism doesn't really play nice with each other, mainly because of the compile time/runtime dichotomy.

Comment: Either `dynamic_cast` or [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).